# ESLint: detecting string interpolation on a specific class/type

Tags: typescript, class, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm using a logger that can accept either string values, like this:

```js
class Logger {
  log(message: string | {message: string, context: {[key: string]: string}}) {
    console.log(message)
  }
}
```

What I want is an ESLint rule that warns if interpolated string values are used on an instance of `Logger`. In that case, I want to guide the user to use the structured context notation instead.

Something like this:

```js
const logger = new Logger();

const str = `some ${'literal'} string`;

// string literal is fine
logger.log('this should be fine');

// structured context object is fine
logger.log({ message: 'This should be fine', context: { foo: 'bar' } });

// this is what we want to avoid...they should use the structured context object instead
logger.log(`Something like ${'this'} is what we want to avoid`);
```

I was looking at the `no-restricted-syntax` rule, but could not figure out how to match an `Identifier` on a *type* of object (in this case `Logger`).

Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure you'll need [a custom eslint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/custom-rules) for this. It's not as hard as it sounds. I made a few for my team and it's been great. You'd basically look for calls to `logger.log`, then look for string interpolation in that calls parameters, and if you find that, then report a problem.

Answer (score 1):

@alex-wayne's comment is right: this is not possible right now with any of the built-in rules in ESLint or typescript-eslint. You'll need to build a custom lint rule. Since what you're trying to scan for involves checking the *type* of nodes (to know whether something is a logger), you'll likely want to use the [typescript-eslint Custom Rules docs](https://typescript-eslint.io/developers/custom-rules).

A version of the rule that doesn't handle annoying edge cases could work like:

1. Find all `TemplateLiteral`s with >0 `arguments` that are the first child of a `CallExpression` whose `callee` is a `MemberExpression` with property `log`
2. Check if the type of the `MemberExpression`'s object appears to be an instance of the `Logger` class

See [Custom Rules > Typed Rules](https://typescript-eslint.io/developers/custom-rules#typed-rules) for how to use TypeScript APIs to grab the type of a node.